# Finding text in p-tag which includes a span-tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Using beautifulsoup I need to find the text inside a `<p>`-tag, which has a `<span>`-tag inside of it, but I am only interested in the text from the `<p>`-tag. And just finding `<p>`-tags gives way too many result, so I want to limit them by the spans.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
text_example = '<p>Hello <span>World</span></p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text_example, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('p').string) # Prints None

print(soup.find('p').find('span').string) # Prints World
```

How do I get the value: 'Hello'?

Comment: this is python, right? please add all appropriate tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `text` and `recursive` parameters in `find`:

```
out = soup.find('p').find(text=True, recursive=False).rstrip()
```

Output:

```
'Hello'
```

Comment: @user16605950  `rstrip` is giving an error when there is no data, so maybe strip trailing empty space only if there is any string (or just remove that part entirely) should do it